# angular route with express not work when refresh

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm try use routing with express and angular . But when I refresh page , in url add `/` and redirect to homepage. 
Here is my strug

```
rootfile
   ||client
      ||home
           home.ejs
      ||view
           index.ejs
```

base

```
<base href="/">
```

server.js
express

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',__dirname +'/client/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
app.get('/*',function(req,res) {
    res.render('index')
});
```

Here is routing

```
function configRouter($stateProvider,$locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $stateProvider
                    .state('home',{
                        url:'/home',
                        templateUrl:'home/home.html',
                        controller:'homeController',
                        controllerAs:'vm'
                    })
            }
```

When I routing to home , it work fine url like this 
`localhost:2912/home` . But when i refresh page it change to `localhost:2912/home/` and redirect to index . WHere is my wrong ?

Comment: don't name a route the same as a partial.  when the `/home` route hits the server, it goes into `/home` and pushes out `home.ejs`, before it hits the `/*` to send the index for angular to run `$stateProvider` from.

Comment: @Claies thank you . It worked

Comment: @Jeet No its not correct . I'm using html5Mode